# Premature End of Script Headers from git-http-backend

Tags: apache, git, msysgit

I am attempting to install git and Apache on Windows.  I have installed MSYSGit 1.7.3 on my Windows 2008 server (x64).  I selected that the git commands should work from a Windows command prompt when I installed msysgit.

I have added these lines to my http.conf file:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT C:/Repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ "C:/Progra~2/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/"

<Directory />
  Options +ExecCGI
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I created a repository (MKE_Playground.git).  I added a file test.txt.

When I attempt to access the URL http://localhost/git/MKE_Playground.git I get this error in the Apache log:

```
[Tue Feb 01 15:56:09 2011] [notice] Child 1164: Child process is running
[Tue Feb 01 15:56:09 2011] [notice] Child 1164: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Feb 01 15:56:09 2011] [notice] Child 1164: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Feb 01 15:56:09 2011] [notice] Child 1164: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2011:15:56:14 -0600] "GET /git/MKE_Playground.git HTTP/1.1" 500 539
[Tue Feb 01 15:56:14 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: git-http-backend.exe
```

I know that this means that the headers from the script were malformed.  If I were writing the script I would check there, but I assume that the git backend typically provides correct headers.  My take on this is that the git http backend failed for some reason.  Where can I go to determine why it failed?  Is there a Git log someplace?

Pat O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have abandonded the idea of running Git on Windows.  As such this is no longer an issue for me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I dealt with a similar problem earlier.

Running "git-http-backend.exe" in a Cygwin shell revealed that the dll, "libiconv2.dll" could not be found. The file is located in the git/bin directory for my Git install (mostly defaults). I added the bin and libexec directories of the git install to my Path, and was able to clone the git repository locally through Apache.

Note: My Apache error logs looked like this - git-http-backend.exe was failing on the missing dll, but not reporting that in the httpd logs:

```
[Mon Feb 14 15:26:02 2011] [notice] Child 3308: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Feb 14 15:26:02 2011] [notice] Child 3308: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Mon Feb 14 15:26:20 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: git-http-backend.exe
[Mon Feb 14 15:26:20 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: git-http-backend.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As far as I can tell it is running correctly. Here is the output from running it from the Git Bash:

<pre>
  pohara@VM-MILLERLITE /c/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core
  $ ./git-http-backend.exe
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
  
  fatal: No REQUEST_METHOD from server
</pre>

Comment: Sorry the previous comment is such a mess.  Can't seems to get the output to be preformatted in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for my 1.7.6.msysgit.0 setup:

In http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/07/31/hosting-a-git-server-under-apache-on-windows/, Jeremy Skinner suggests that it must be possible to run Git\libexec\git-http-backend.exe in a Windows cmd shell. When this fails, copy Git\bin\libiconv-2.dll and Git\bin\libiconv2.dll to Git\libexec\git-core and try again. If you can call git-http-backend.exe and it gives you a "500 Internal Server Error", try your clone or fetch again.

Answer (score 1):

I was fighting the same issue. In my case it was a user permission problem. You can check the "log on" information for the Apache Windows Service and test with your domain user for instance (Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services->Apache->Log On Tab).

After a reboot, browsing to your http://localhost/git/MKE_Playground.git should then give you a Request not supported error in your error.log. That's fine.

git clone http://localhost/git/MKE_Playground.git should work then.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had setup an appropriate user for Apache to run under already though.